# Am I creating a MySQL table I don't need?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query a database and I think my query could probably be shortened to eliminate a subquery, but every attempt I make to do so results in some kind of error (I am somewhat new to SQL).

The database gives information on school demographics by age and gender groups. I am trying to get summary information about gender with the following query:

```
SELECT i.id AS id,
  (SELECT group_concat(entry separator '`')
   FROM
     (SELECT school_id,
             concat(gender, '|', sum(percentage)) AS entry
      FROM school_demographics
      GROUP BY gender,
               school_id) AS s1
   WHERE s1.school_id = i.id ) AS demographics
FROM school_info i
WHERE i.id = 500;
```

This works, and combines everything I need into one string of the form `` female|65.4`male|34.4 ``
(as I want), but I have this feeling one of the subqueries is not needed, specifically where I am returning a column `AS entry` only to use it in group_concat above. Am I correct in thinking that there's an easier way to make this query work?

Comment: That query looks especially complex. Are you sure there isn't a simpler way of doing this? Doing all that formatting within the database is often a waste of effort as you can do it in the application layer with a lot more control. Just because you *can* do it in SQL doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I spent a very long time writing that query and I agree. Unfortunately the constraint I am working with is that the result has to return exactly one row for each queried id, no more.

Comment: The join with `school_info` seems to be unnecessary. You could as good have the condition `WHERE s1.school_id = 500` in the first subquery. But you need at least one subquery, if you want to agregate twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that subqueries having connections with each other can have poor performance

```
select i.id,group_concat(d.gender,'|',d.p separator '`')
from
 (select school_id,gender,sum(percentage) as p
  from school_demographics
  group by school_id,gender
  ) d
  join school_info i on i.id=d.school_id
group by i.id
where i.id=500;
```

`where i.id=500` could be removed

Answer (score 1):

> the result has to return exactly one row for each queried id

That doesn't mean, it can't return multiple colums. So you might try conditional aggregation (assuming you have only `female` and `male` in the `gender` column):

```
SELECT school_id,
    SUM(CASE gender WHEN 'female' THEN percentage END) as percentage_female,
    SUM(CASE gender WHEN 'male'   THEN percentage END) as percentage_male
FROM school_demographics
GROUP BY school_id
WHERE school_id = 500
```

The result should look like:

```
school_id | percentage_female | percentage_male
      500 |              65.4 |            34.4
```